# Pandas Apply on previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I *think* that `pandas` probably allows what I want to do in a clever way that will avoid a loop, but I do not know how to structure it.

## Problem

I want to perform a calculation using the previous row of a dataset *and outside data*.

I can conceptually explain my problem fairly simply: I am trying to measure the volume of fluid in a tank.  Some liquid will flow in, and some will flow out. But I also need to know the previous volume to know the new volume:

```py
def new_volume(previous_volume, overall_flow):
    return previous_volume + overall_flow

df.loc[:,volume_col].apply(new_volume, flow_delta)
```

Of course, what I wrote above does not give me what I want because it will be off by one.  Is there any way to say that I want to use the *last row* when using `apply` for the function call?

I would like for something like the function above to use the volume in row (i - 1) to generate the volume in row (i).

It is *sort of like* using `pandas`' `cumulative_sum`, but with an `apply` function.  I am hoping there might be something similar to that which I can do.  But I did not find any `cumulative_apply`.

Comment: Could you add some examples of your data frame and `flow_delta`?

Comment: You can get the previous row's volume with `df[volume_col].shift()`. You may not need an `apply` at all. Add some sample input and expected output for a better answer

Comment: Thank you, @CodeDifferent !  I knew about `shift`, but forgot about it.  I'm not sure if I should delete this question, or leave it for others, but `shift` does take care of the problem.  :)